# How to subtract a list of values from a column every each group of rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, subtraction

I have a list of values:

```
T=['23','22','13','25','33','21','20']
```

and a file containing one column and 14 rows:

```
24
25
-9999
0
35
39
40
33
44
45
27
39
35
39
```

Code:

```
df - pd.Series(T)
```

I want to subtract the list T (i.e. containing 7 rows) from the column of the file every 7 rows but ignoring values with -9999 and 0. How I could do that with pandas in python?

```
 df.mask(df.isin([-9999, 0]))
```

The expected output would be like:

```
   col  new
0    24    1
1    25    3
2    15    0
3    27    0
4    35    2
5    39   18
6    40   20
7    33   10
8    44   22
9    45   32
10   27    2
11   39    6
12   35   14
13   39   19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) for repeat values of list, filter by length of `df`, convert to integers and subtract is simpliest and fastest solution:

```
T=('23','22','13','25','33','21','20')

#if there is always 14 rows
#df['new'] = df['col'].sub(np.tile(T,2).astype(int))

#any rows
df['new'] = df['col'].sub(np.tile(T, len(df) // len(T) + 2)[:len(df)].astype(int))
print (df)
    col  new
0    24    1
1    25    3
2    15    2
3    27    2
4    35    2
5    39   18
6    40   20
7    33   10
8    44   22
9    45   32
10   27    2
11   39    6
12   35   14
13   39   19
```

Or is possible use align by index values between new `Series` and original `df.index` with integer division:

```
T=('23','22','13','25','33','21','20')


df.index = df.index % len(T) 
df['new'] = df['col'].sub(pd.Series(T).astype(int).loc[df.index])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    col  new
0    24    1
1    25    3
2    15    2
3    27    2
4    35    2
5    39   18
6    40   20
7    33   10
8    44   22
9    45   32
10   27    2
11   39    6
12   35   14
13   39   19
```

Or is possible subtract per groups, it is slowiest solution:

```
f  = lambda x: x.sub(np.array(T).astype(int))
df['new'] = df.groupby(df.index // len(T))['col'].transform(f)

print (df)
    col  new
0    24    1
1    25    3
2    15    2
3    27    2
4    35    2
5    39   18
6    40   20
7    33   10
8    44   22
9    45   32
10   27    2
11   39    6
12   35   14
13   39   19
```

EDIT: For set `0` by condition use after my solution `loc` or `mask`:

```
df.loc[df['col'].isin([-9999, 0]), 'new'] = 0
#alternative
#df['new'] = df['new'].mask(df['col'].isin([-9999, 0]), 0)

print (df)
     col  new
0     24    1
1     25    3
2  -9999    0
3      0    0
4     35    2
5     39   18
6     40   20
7     33   10
8     44   22
9     45   32
10    27    2
11    39    6
12    35   14
13    39   19
```

Comment: Thank you a lot it worked. What about if I want to ignore specific values? How i could add the restriction e.g. df.mask(df.isin([-9999, 0])) ?

Comment: @Nat - I think for beeter understanding is possible change data sample with `-9999` and `0` and add expected ouput after subtract?